# Jquery validation for dynamic text box

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, onchange

I am using jquery validation , its working fine but I am using dynamic text boxes which are being visible by onchange of select option in my form. how does i validate my dynamic text box according to onchange in select.

Comment: The only solution is provide your code...So that you will be get helped easily..Or wait until the question gets closed...

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Ironically, a google search for _your exact question_ returns dozens of answers about validating a dynamic form. Please learn to search.

Comment: I'm also faced this issue... but i solved it... wait i will provide some sample code.

Comment: put normal validation as others.If the text box is visible it ask for validation if it is hidden not ask.

Comment: @Aditi http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/concrete5-javascript-jquery-php-and-mysql-issues

Comment: @Aditi Improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

use `if` condition in `required`. for example,

```
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            text1: {
                required: function (element) {
                    if ($("#selid").val() == '1') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
            text2: {
                required: function (element) {
                    if ($("#selid").val() == '2') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

consider `#selid` is id of your `select` control. If select value '1'  only it will reflect `text1` will be `required true`. other wise, it will `required false`.
In the same way If select value '2'  only it will reflect `text2` will be `required true`. other wise, it will `required false`.

like this you can apply to your code...

See [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/grEbZ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of depends in Jquery Validate so your code will look like

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        txt1: {
            required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return ($("#drp").val() == '1')
                }
            }
        },
        txt2: {
           required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return ($("#drp").val() == '2')
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```